# WP7 - compass pointer

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Sorry for the really general question, but I don't have a clue where to start. There's a component I want to develop for a WP7 application which is a an arrow that points in the direction (preferable X, Y, Z planes) of an address from where the user is currently located.

So for example, if you're lost in the woods and you have the address (long/latitude) of your house, it will always point you home.

Anyone know of any way to get started with this or samples or.....?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the release of Mango you can now use the [Compass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.sensors.compass%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) class.

There is also the [Raw Sensor Data Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#BKMK_Sensors) and [How to: Get Data from the Compass Sensor for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202974%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately as of January 2011, Microsoft has not yet exposed the compass functionality with a public API. You'll have to wait till a later release for that.

If you are interested in the Latitude and Longitude, the [GeoCoordinateWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher(v=VS.92).aspx) is the place to start.

Comment: Is there a different way? I've seen apps that point people to Mecca from their current location, so I'm assuming there must be something that allows for this functionality.

Comment: Are you sure it was pointing them, or just displaying a route? You can get the Latitude/Longitude and display a route, but orienting the map with the compass isn't possible right now.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can write so many miles East/West/North/South on the app page ( not worth much) if required.
2. You can even show a dynamic bing map with an indication of current location and destination using pins. But can't show the directions/orientation of the device w.r.t. actual direction.

You can get current GPS location and home GPS location. check the location service API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431803.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Cant you use the GeoCoordinate.Course to get direction you are going?

Sebulba

Comment: don't know. how does that translate into a a set of `Point`?